# Problema intermitente com Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'locac' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Estou tendo este problema

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'locac' of undefined

Com o código:

```js
function fnc(){    
    var evt = (window.event ? window.event : event);
    var elemento = evt.target;
    var params = $(elemento).data('params');
    alert(params.locac);
}

$('body').on('click','button.inst',fnc);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" data-params='{"locac":"reg","titulo":"Inserir Registro"}' class="btn btn-success inst">Inserir</button>
```

Link do exemplo: [**exemplo**](http://jsfiddle.net/welguri/rdfcz0y4/1/)

Mas nem sempre o erro ocorre, tem hora que clico no botão várias vezes e não dá este erro, mais tem vezes que clico uma vez e já dá erro.

As vezes dá erro e não dá erro.

O erro só vejo no *mundo real*

Comment: Ta funcionando corretamente sempre aqui para mim, tanto no snipper aqui do SO, quando no jsFiddle. (estou testando no Chrome), para você não funciona?

Comment: estou no chrome também, dentro do jsFiddle percebi que não gera erro em nenhum momento mais por algum motivo dentro do codigo original da o erro citado acima.. @Fernando

Comment: Se o erro não é reproduzível é complicado alguém poder lhe ajudar, pois pode ser qualquer coisa em seu ambiente, e que não está acessível a nós através da questão. Mesmo assim, vou tentar ajudar, a primeira coisa que me vem a mente é versão de jQuery, qual você está utilizando?

Comment: @Fernando Jquery2.1.3, e neste exemplo meu tem um erro pois o Firefox não reconhece o event global, tive que passar por parâmetros, mais esta parte esta blz.

Answer (score 1):

Não há erros aparentes em seu código, mas creio que a solução seja colocar seu script dentro do evento de `ready` do jQuery. Leia [aqui](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/).

Faça assim:

```
$(function () {
    function fnc(){    
        var evt = (window.event ? window.event : event);
        var elemento = evt.target;
        var params = $(elemento).data('params');
        alert(params.locac);
    }

    $('body').on('click','button.inst',fnc);
});
```

É uma boa prática sempre usar esse padrão quando precisar manipular o DOM.

Comment: A estrutura HTML é carregada via ajax, e este botão vem jundo com este HTML.

Comment: Editarei a pergunta assim que possível.